# How to present view controller behind another view controller?

Tags: objective-c, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, segue, uistoryboard

I am trying to present two view controllers. I'm trying to avoid presenting one after the other as this doesn't give a good user experience.

I'm using storyboards / segues to present the view controllers, each embedded in navigation controllers.

The behaviour should be:

View Controller 1 presents view controller 2 - but when view controller 2 dismisses I'd like view controller 3 to be the one showing to the user. And ideally an ability to also dismiss to view controller 1.

I understand I can accomplish this with child views. But I'd ideally like to learn how it can be done by manipulating the navigation stack.

Comment: How are you presenting it? "Push" segue in a UINavigationController? Modal slide-up -and-cover presentation?

Comment: add your language tag, it is the main in always

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do what you want with `segue`, but certainly you can do it with a little code...

This will (on a button tap, for example) perform a standard slide-in navigation controller animation directly from the current ViewController (call it `vc1`) to `ViewController2`, but "insert" `ViewController3` into the stack. Tapping the Back button will take you from `vc2` to `vc3` to `vc1`.

```
@IBAction func didTap(_ sender: Any) {

    guard let vc3 = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vc3"),
        let vc2 = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vc2")
        else { return }

    let vcArray = [self, vc3, vc2]

    self.navigationController?.setViewControllers(vcArray, animated: true)

}
```

If you want to go from `vc2` back to `vc1` and "skip over" `vc3`, in `vc2` add (on a button tap, for example):

```
@IBAction func backToStartTap(_ sender: Any) {

    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As best to my understanding about your question, try out below method:

Present VC 3 from VC 1 and from VC 3 present VC 2 immediately(This can be done by putting the viewController present code in the ViewDidLoad() of VC 3).

So when you dismiss VC 2, VC 3 will be shown and on dismissing VC 3 , you will be redirected to VC 1.

*VC means ViewController.*

Answer (score 0):

Presenting viewController in the *ViewDidLoad()* is really a ***bad idea.***

You can present VC3 and add VC1.view and VC2.view as a subview of VC3's view and later you can remove VC1.view and VC2.view as you want and behaviour will be same as you are expecting.

Comment: actually you cannot present or push another ViewController in viewDidLoad() method. Writing code for push or presenting ViewController in viewDidLoad will have no effect.

Comment: @K.R.SaravanaKumar : Yes, that's what i'm saying my friend. We are not supposed to present or push a VC in viewDidLoad() method.

**Check first line.**
**Presenting viewController in the ViewDidLoad() is really a bad idea.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your the viewcontroller you are going to present .modalPresentationStyle as .currentContext, and you need to set your current viewcontroller .definesPresentationContext as false